Banno Garden External Application Sample - Experian Card?
In the Garden test application, there is the sample card for Experian. It's dynamic and when clicking "View More" it opens an external application with a "Back to Dashboard" link in the menu.
I cannot find documentation on how to handle that link back as well. Are there any full featured examples that showcase how that card works?

That's an actual plugin card from the folks at Array, so we don't have a code sample for that particular plugin at Jack Henry.
The "Back to Dashboard" button in Array's plugin simply navigates to the base URL of Banno Online for the Garden demo institution, i.e. navigates folks to https://digital.garden-fi.com.
In terms of example apps, we have these (although none use a "Back to Dashboard" type of navigation):

https://github.com/Banno/simple-plugin-example
https://github.com/Banno/basic-plugin-example

